I cannot get PUT Ajax data in Laravel
I have a form like this:
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.update', $user->id) }}" method="PUT" class="formajax_popup">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" class="form-control">
                        </div>
...
</form>

I automatically convert this form to ajax with a javascript class.Methods and values remain as they are.
This is the request I sent: Headers:
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/11
Request Method:
PUT
Status Code:
500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Date: Fri, 02 Aug 2024 01:09:47 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.12
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
PUT /admin/users/11 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 783
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

o9U1I2VBuhQvx6Zmcsl1wS98FcpP6XYHZkOtlbPD
------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"

PUT
------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Duran Can YILMAZ
------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

test@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"


------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roles[]"

Super Admin
------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT--

If I do request->all() in laravel, it naturally outputs this way.
array:1 [ // app\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController.php:81
  "------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name" => """
    "_token"

    

    o9U1I2VBuhQvx6Zmcsl1wS98FcpP6XYHZkOtlbPD

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"

    

    PUT

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

    

    Duran Can YILMAZ

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

    

    test@gmail.com

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

    

    

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="undefined"

    

    

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT

    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roles[]"

    

    Super Admin

    ------WebKitFormBoundary1ouCYkAGCeExrdsT--
    """
]

I am using Route::resource and the ajax package I wrote (https://github.com/duran004/FormAjax) so I don't want to POST the form method. Because of HTTP standards. I want the form method to remain as PUT.
Does anyone have a solution other than parse the data?
Laravel route:
Route::resource('users', AdminUserController::class);

The javascript part sends it briefly like this:
submit(form) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const formUrl = $(form).attr('action');
        const formMethod = $(form).attr('method').toLowerCase();
        const allElements = $(form).find(this.elementsSelector);
        const checkboxNames = new Set();
        var csrfInput = $(form).find('input[name="_token"]');
        this.csrfToken = csrfInput.length ? csrfInput.val() : null;
        const contentTypes = {
            'post': 'application/json',
            'put': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'delete': 'application/json',
            'get': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
        this.log(`form_url: ${formUrl} 
            form_method: ${formMethod} 
            content_type: ${contentTypes[formMethod]}
            csrf_token: ${this.csrfToken}`);
        allElements.each((_, element) => {
            const $element = $(element);
            if ($element.is(':checkbox')) {
                const name = $element.attr('name');
                checkboxNames.add(name);
            } else {
                formData.append($element.attr('name'), $element.val());
            }
        });

        checkboxNames.forEach(name => {
            $(form).find(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`).each((_, el) => {
                formData.append(name, $(el).val()); // Append each checked value
            });
        });

        console.log(`form_data:`);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            method: formMethod,
            data: formData,
            processData: false, // Do not process data
            // contentType: false, // Do not set content type

            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.csrfToken,
                'Content-Type': contentTypes[formMethod]
            },
            success: (response, status, xhr) => {
                console.log(response);
                //if status start with 2
                if (xhr.status.toString().startsWith('2')) {
                    if (response.status) {
                        this.handleSuccess(response);
                    } else {
                        this.handleError(response);
                    }
                } else if (xhr.status.toString().startsWith('4')) {
                    this.handleError(response, 400);
                } else if (xhr.status.toString().startsWith('5')) {
                    this.handleError(response, 500);
                } else if (xhr.status.toString().startsWith('3')) {
                    this.handleError(response, 300);
                } else if (xhr.status.toString().startsWith('1')) {
                    this.handleError(response, 100);
                } else {
                    this.handleError(xhr);
                }
            },
            error: (xhr) => this.handleError(xhr),
        });
    }

form_url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/11
form_method: put
content_type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
csrf_token: o9U1I2VBuhQvx6Zmcsl1wS98FcpP6XYHZkOtlbPD

According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3 standards, I want to implement put patch methods in laravel only with ajax.
What is expected is this: To send variables as it sends in the POST method. Or the variables can be easily parse on the laravel $request side.

You're sending multipart/form-data, not application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is notoriously difficult to handle as raw body content in PHP

Hello @Phil , can you please specify exactly where I sent the multipart/form-data? Because as I wrote, in the request headers section in the browser, content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Using a FormData instance for your request body automatically uses multipart/form-data. Manually setting the content-type header has no effect. Try URLSearchParams instead

@Phil he's using Laravel, it's not difficult at all to receive those types of inputs

The issue is that you're using method="PUT" on the form tag. Just use method="POST" as the method, but keep the @method('PUT') on your blade template so Laravel can treat the request as PUT.
More info: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#method-field
